# How to convert a string into a 16 bit big endian integer?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement https://github.com/NuVotifier/NuVotifier/wiki/Technical-QA using c# but I'm having issues with the 16 bit big endian integer part.

A message composed of 0x733A (16-bit big-endian integer) and the length of the following JSON message (as a 16-bit big-endian integer) sent plus the message.

I've tried doing something like this using https://www.nuget.org/packages/EndianBitConverter

```
byte[] firstPart = EndianBitConverter.BigEndian.GetBytes(Convert.ToInt32("0x733A"));
byte[] secondPart = EndianBitConverter.BigEndian.GetBytes(long.Parse(output.Length.ToString()));
```

However, it's saying its invalid and the only part that I can see being wrong is converting them in big endian.

Comment: Can you please provide a full [mre] including the setup?

Comment: what is your expected output here? 29498 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```cs
    static void Main()
    {
        var span = "0x733A".AsSpan();
        // strip the 0x if present
        if (span.StartsWith("0x")) span = span.Slice(2);
        Debug.Assert(span.Length == 4); // we expect 2 bytes

        ushort result = (ushort) (
            Nibble(span[0]) << 12 | Nibble(span[1]) << 8 |
            Nibble(span[2]) << 4 | Nibble(span[3])
        );

        Console.WriteLine(result); // 29498

    }
    static ushort Nibble(char c)
    {
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') return (byte)(c - '0');
        if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') return (byte)(c - 'a' + 10);
        if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') return (byte)(c - 'A' + 10);
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(c));
    }
```